# Navigate between views in a TabHost

Tags: android, android-widget, android-tabhost, tabwidget

My application is based on a TabWidget; in a TabHost I have an Activity (ProductsActivity) showing some products pictures. Tapping on a picture I want to show the detail for the selected product (through another activity, ProductDetailActivity) remaining in the same tabHost. What is the correct way for navigate back and forth between the product list and details in the same tab?

By calling startActivity the new activity is not in the TabWidget.